# MongoDB search in array of sub documents

Tags: mongodb

I have this data in mongodb. my query is not matching this record.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a60fd777f57eea025f0521d"),
    "groupname" : "my Users",
    "memberes" : [ 
        {
            "CN" : "john, miller",
            "employeeNumber" : "865",

        }, 
        {
            "CN" : "sunil, kumar",
            "employeeNumber" : "456",

        }
    ]
}
```

**query**

```
db.collection.find( { "memberes": { "employeeNumber" : "456"} } )
```

Can help me to correct this query?

Thanks
SR

Comment: Looks at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083603/mongodb-c-sharp-complex-query/48083997#48083997 It's C# but you can use the same approach for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002659/how-to-query-nested-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002659/how-to-query-nested-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)

The corrected query according to these materials would be:

`db.collection.find({ "memberes.employeeNumber" : "456"})`